Fintuning Time of LoRA
I tried lora (on ViT) and i thought it would reduce the finetuning time, but it is same. is it right??
I checked that the original network's weights are forzen correctly.
Then LoRA's advantage is reduction of computing resource, not time?

I suppose it is both time and memory actually.
In case you do not quantize the weights and leave them as is (and without gradient checkpointing etc.), when using LoRA you only have to do backprop for a subset of weights, which reduces the finetuning time.
On the other had, you often find yourself with a consumer grade GPU and frequently forced to apply quantize the weights (sometimes even apply double quantization) and you have to dequantize them for the forward and backward passes, this will result in a performance drop.
